# Time Parameters of Mishenichnas Adar Marbin B'Simcha

Tags: calendar, simchah-joy-happiness, adar

Is "Mishenichnas Adar Marbin B'Simcha" just for the month of Adar, and then you take a step down in simcha for Nisan? Or are you supposed to raise your level of simcha and stay there until Av, when you're supposed to decrease your joy? If it's just for Adar, why? What about the other months in which we were saved in some way (Nisan, Kislev)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the Michtav M'Eliyahu (Vol. 2 pg 125) on the essay titled "משנכנס אדר" he discusses how the command `to be joyous when Adar enters` is related to the joy of Purim.

He explains that the happiness we feel on Purim is a הכרת הטוב - recognizing the goodness - of the miracle of Purim, which is all about revenge. HaShem took revenge on Haman and ונהפוך הוא - turned the tables - and made Mordechai the *Prime Minister* in his stead.

The joy required to celebrate this הכרת הטוב efficiently requires work and preparation, continues the Michtav M'Eliyahu, and one needs to start this preparation as soon as Adar starts, in order to be *in the right mood* when Purim arrives.

> ומתחילין כבר מראש חודש לגודל ההכנה הנדרשת, וממשיכים בעבודה זו מיום ליום

The Ramchal (Derech HaShem ח"ד פ"ח)  says that the point of the joy of Purim is the קבלת התורה - celebrating the re-acceptance of the Torah.

So - using the reasoning of the Michtav M'Eliyahu - we would say that we need the 2 weeks to prepare for it; similar to the 49 days to prepare for Shavuoth.

So - back to the question - once Purim is over, one can *wind down* and get ready for entering the Pessach *mood*. Each Chag has its own *mood* and preparation period.

Comment: This was a really great answer - thanks so much for taking the time to write it!

Answer (score 5):

Rashi to [Taanis 29a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=10&daf=29&format=pdf) writes that the reason for increasing joy upon the entrance of Adar is that it is a time of miracles, *such as Purim and Pesach*.

The implication of Rashi is that this simcha should last until Pesach, as that is still the time period of the miracles which cause this to be a season of simcha.

(And perhaps you should sing the jingle until then as well, but I can't guarentee you'll have any friends by the time Pesach comes.)

Answer (score 0):

This question is addressed in introduction to the sefer [Targum Simcha](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=66549&st=&pgnum=8).

There, it says that the joy that began in Adar reaches its pinnacle on Erev Rosh Chodesh Av, prior to the instruction to begin decreasing joy.

Comment: Seems odd to forbid weddings etc. on erev rosh chodesh av then.

Comment: From the text it seems that the joy should be expressed in a manner of tefillah.

Comment: Ok, no tachanun for iyyar sivan and tammuz

Comment: The text that i quoted in my answer quotes from tehilim עבדו את ה' בשמחה. I think that would apply also to times when tachnun is said. Again, the original question was about extending the joy of Adar, and i provided a source that discusses it. I think my Answer to the question adequately address the question asked.

Comment: I'm not saying it doesn't appear to address the question, I'm saying it seems obviously untenable.

Comment: I think it would have been more straightforward and clear had you just commented "To me it seems untenable to achieve". I think it was confusing when you started mentioning about tachnun and weddings.

Comment: Not untenable to achieve. Untenable. The fact is we do not and for 2000 years have not treated erev rosh chodesh av as the pinnacle of simcha.

Comment: I think The Targum Simcha is saying (from what is written) that since Joy is important to have throughout the year. During times when we are sad - such as the 3 weeks, there is still a way to find joy, which is that in the tefilos (he specifically writes tefilos) of erev rosh chodesh Av, it can be understood to be a heightened level of joy, prior to the instruction to decrease our joy. I don't think he is insinuating that it necessitates throwing a party, but that there is room for him to say to daven with joy. Personally i think davening with joy is always good.