# Going to men's mikva at night

Tags: halacha, minhag, mikvah-ritual-bath, evening-night

Is there any issue for men going to the mikva at night? The customary thing seems to be to go before davening in the morning, or in the afternoon on erev Shabbos or Yom Tov, or at dawn on leil Shavuos, etc. What about during actual nighttime?

Comment: related info https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/3997062/jewish/Why-Men-Immerse-in-the-Mikvah-Every-Day.htm

Comment: The Mishna tells of Kohanim who would dip at night (Tamid 1). Not sure what the problem would be.

Comment: @DoubleAA Maybe וקדשתו.

Comment: @Yez hmm? כי את לחם אלהיך הוא מקריב? What does that have to do with anything

Comment: @DoubleAA 'Twas a joke. My שיטה on how long Purim Torah season lasts is documented [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/66069/4794)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm unaware of any halacha that prohibits men from going to the mikvah at night (other than Yom Kippur and Tisha B'av.) I've occasionally seen men do this in my neighborhood.

However, practically, in many neighborhoods that have one mikvah or even a few, most of these are used by women for their *tahara* that ends *niddah*. So, of course, not only can't men go when women are there, but they really shouldn't even be roaming or "loitering" anywhere near the mikvah at night when women are there.

Ideally, places have dedicated men's only mikva'ot so going at night to these poses no problem. I recommend that before you go at night, inquire about the mikvah's night usage.

Incidentally, I have heard of some places that send men to "dunk" in the *keilim* mikvah - the one that's used for utensils. Apparently, this occurs somewhat more frequently than I imagined. The keilim mikvah tends to be ice cold and, honestly, not only would I not want to dunk my body in the keilim mikvah but, I wouldn't want to dunk my *kli* in that mikvah afterwards. So, somewhat aside, but, perhaps, relevant - anyone that thinks of going to a "men's mikvah" should ask about this. It's not always obvious if you're unfamiliar with the mikvah setup of that place, and, unfortunately, many places aren't volunteering this info.

Comment: Most men's mikvaos that I'm familiar with, have a policy of being open only from early to late mornings. Otherwise it can become a hangout for sleazy characters.

Comment: @IsraelReader It's unfortunate that we have to hear even a smidgen of something like that. While I certainly understand how hard and costly it is to build and maintain a mikvah, in larger communities where they can afford it, I don't think that there should ever be a combo mens / women's mikvah. And one layer of protection should be that all women's mikva'ot should be gated and locked at all times and only members should have a key. A guard and a few escorts would also help things even more.

Comment: I agree with your comments about combo mikvas, and the preference for a separate all woman's mikva, and appropriate security. My comment was directed exclusively to men's mikvas, addressing an unfortunate reality that there perverts and deviants who take advantage of the fact that the mikva is open at unusual hours, and there is little other traffic to prevent them from doing inappropriate things there.

Comment: @IsraelReader Oy. I hadn't even considered that. That's even worse. This happens in Israel?

Comment: There are some men's mikvos that I know about which are open in the morning for the public, and then is available by key to members only.

Comment: @user218076 That seems to be a balanced approach, and hopefully keys are only given to TRUSTED members.

Comment: @DanF Since the Yetzer Hara works internationally, the problem is worldwide. I'm glad that you were sheltered from this reality.

Answer (score 2):

As stated by others -- primarily it's about giving the women their own space and time.

But furthermore -- the primary halachic grounding for men going to mikva today is the enactment of Ezra against studying Torah after a seminal emission without first going to mikvah. If someone followed that, it would make sense for them to go to mikvah in the morning, before studying Torah.

But supposing that a man (and his wife) were on a nocturnal schedule and thus he wakes up at 9pm and wants to study Torah now, then yes following this logic that would be the time to go to mikvah.